# PHP: What's wrong with this code?

Tags: php, variables, scope, global-variables

Sorry for such a vague title but I am unsure what to put for it. So I am practicing my `PHP` skills and I wrote the following code.

```
<?php

$FavPeople = array
    (
    'Sofia', 'Love of my life',
    'Jesus', 'Savior of my soul',
    'Austin', 'Favorite Nephew'
    );

function randomPerson()
{

    $total = count($FavPeople);
    $ranNumber = rand(0, $total-1);

    echo $FavPeople[$ranNumber] . '</br>';

}

randomPerson();

?>
```

When run, `$FavPeople` is undefined or not accessable because its Global scope. So I said 'okay, i'll just do this:

```
global $FavPeople
```

in my function.
It doesn't run. Instead, I get a blank screen and no error.

If I copy and paste my $FavPeople into the function, it works, but typing global $FavPeople inside the function, makes it not work. Why is this?

Comment: try with add global before array like global $FavPeople = array(----);

Comment: one way is to add a parameter on your function.. like `randomPerson($person)`.. then supply `$FavPeople` array on it..

Comment: use it as `randomPerson($FavPeople)` and `function randomPerson($FavPeople)`

Comment: `randomPerson($FavPeople);` and `function randomPerson($FavPeople)`

Comment: It is working with `global`. https://eval.in/543729

Comment: I posted the answer refering comments from Anant and Saty .and it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did small modification referring  the comments . You do not need to specify it as global, you can just pass it as parameter by making slide change in function signature.

```
 <?php

    $FavPeople = array
        (
        'Sofia', 'Love of my life',
        'Jesus', 'Savior of my soul',
        'Austin', 'Favorite Nephew'
        );

    function randomPerson($FavPeople)
    {

        $total = count($FavPeople);
        $ranNumber = rand(0, $total-1);

        echo $FavPeople[$ranNumber] . '</br>';

    }

    randomPerson($FavPeople);

    ?>
```

### output

Love of my life

### Reload

Sofia

........

If you want it to be global there are two way.

1)

```
 global $FavPeople;


function randomPerson()
{

    $FavPeople = array
    (
    'Sofia', 'Love of my life',
    'Jesus', 'Savior of my soul',
    'Austin', 'Favorite Nephew'
    );


    $total = count($FavPeople);
    $ranNumber = rand(0, $total-1);

    echo $FavPeople[$ranNumber] . '</br>';

}

randomPerson();
```

2)

```
  <?php

$FavPeople = array
    (
    'Sofia', 'Love of my life',
    'Jesus', 'Savior of my soul',
    'Austin', 'Favorite Nephew'
    );

function randomPerson()
{
    global $FavPeople;
    $total = count($FavPeople);
    $ranNumber = rand(0, $total-1);

    echo $FavPeople[$ranNumber] . '</br>';

}

randomPerson();
```

The two way I have descibed are same , the first one seems me more correct as the code is clear. if you declare a global variable inside a function , after a year or some time, you will be confused, if the code will be too long.

And it also states, you were not using the global correctly.

check this : -https://eval.in/543767

Comment: I marked this one as "right", because it works, but it didn't really answer my question. I was wondering why the global $FavPeople inside my function isn't working. It should 'import' so to say, the variable inside my local scope, but it does not.

Comment: ok, I am going to edit my answer.

Comment: @user2763154 if you can declare the $FavPeople as global inside the function, it is working, if you declare it global outside the function, may be the function is treating it as two different variable.

Comment: @user2763154 please check the answer, I have edited it, I hope now it will e more clear to you.

Comment: @user2763154 let me know, if you want to ask anything more about it.

Comment: I copied and pasted your last answer to see the results, and I still got a blank spot where the text should be, however, I am getting the noticable </br> new line break. So I don't know why the text is not appearing, but the break line is. I think its because i'm using Drupal and maybe my code isn't compatiable with the API, but I take it that this works and its just Drupal at this point. Thank you sir.

Comment: @user2763154 I have updated the 2nd way again, and tested it in my localhost, please check it on your server, it is working.All of the 3 are working in my localhost, so please check it another time, by creating separate files.

Comment: @user2763154 check https://eval.in/543767

Answer (score 0):

Just add global before the variable within the function.

```
function randomPerson(){

    global $FavPeople;   // Add this
    $total = count($FavPeople);
    $ranNumber = rand(0, $total-1);
    echo $FavPeople[$ranNumber] . '</br>';
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work for some reason. I"m wondering why because from my understand, this is how your "suppose" to do it, for getting globals inside your local scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$FavPeople = array
    (
    'Sofia', 'Love of my life',
    'Jesus', 'Savior of my soul',
    'Austin', 'Favorite Nephew'
    );

function randomPerson()
{
    global $FavPeople ;
    $total = count($FavPeople);
    $ranNumber = rand(0, $total-1);

    echo $FavPeople[$ranNumber] . '</br>';

}

randomPerson();

?>
```

Comment: For your code, it will work, but the problem is when the code will be too long you will be confused , so check my answer, I have posted 2 way . you will get the idea.

Comment: Thanks @PrafullaKumarSahu